# Search for a single character like '@' or '%' in Word Document using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need help in knowing the faster way to search any character like '@' or '&' or '*' in a large Word Document with around 4-5000 lines in it.

Currently I am searching through each character via For-Loop which takes a very long time to search the characters.

```
public void SearchFunc()
{
    cursorPos = 0;
    docReadCount = 0;

    flag:

    for (int i = cursorPos; i < docEndPos; i++)
    {

        if (i + 1 == docEndPos|| i == docEndPos)
        {
            if(docReadCount == 1) return;
            cursorPos = 0;
            docReadCount++;
            goto flag;
        }

        if (doc.Range(i, i+ 1).Text == "@" || 
            doc.Range(i, i+ 1).Text == "&" || 
            doc.Range(i, i+ 1).Text == "*")
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Regex `([@&\*])` to check if there is one of these tree chars (`@`, `&`, `*`) in the String:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String test = "this is a @test & when ist asd*sd";

        if (Regex.Match(test, "([@&\\*])").Success) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("%, & or * found!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Q:** I need to know the cursor position as well of the character in the document. By using regex how can I know that ?

**A:**
Yes, it is supported by the Regex class. There is a property called `Index` for each `Match`:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String test = "this is a @test & when ist asd*sd";

        Match match = Regex.Match(test, "([@&\\*])");

        int i = 0;
        while (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index of Match No."+ i.ToString()
                              + " (char "+ match.Value +"): "
                              + match.Index.ToString());
            match = match.NextMatch();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

> Index of Match No.0 (char @): 10
>   Index of Match No.1 (char &): 16
>   Index of Match No.2 (char *): 30

Comment: @Maximilian_Ast Thanks, I implemented this code in my application, but this approach is also taking around 12-15 minimum seconds to go through all the 4000-5000 lines of text.

I want something similar to how Find (Ctrl+F) works in Webpages, Text Files, etc. It searches for a word instantly no matter how big the file is.

Comment: I ran the scrip with a String containing 25000 random chars and it took less than 1 sek execution time (generating the String + seraching for) https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ynm4Aj